# Querying Operating System information with Visual c++

Tags: visual-c++, wmi, hardware

The below code is a sample code from the msdn([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) about how to query operating information using WMI. When running this code in visual c++ 2010, i get the following error :

> "Unhandled exception at 0x5a2c47af (msvcr100d.dll) in ProjectTest.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccffff."

Can anyone help me please with this issue?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>

# pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

int main()
{
    HRESULT hres;

    // Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
    // Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return 1;                  // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------
    // Note: If you are using Windows 2000, you need to specify -
    // the default authentication credentials for a user by using
    // a SOLE_AUTHENTICATION_LIST structure in the pAuthList ----
    // parameter of CoInitializeSecurity ------------------------

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );


    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                    // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
    // Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

    hres = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_WbemLocator,             
        0, 
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
        IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object."
            << " Err code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                 // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
    // Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

    IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

    // Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
    // the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
    // to make IWbemServices calls.
    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
         _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
         NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
         NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
         0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
         NULL,                    // Security flags.
         0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
         0,                       // Context object 
         &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
         );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" 
             << hex << hres << endl;
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;                // Program has failed.
    }

    cout << "Connected to ROOT\\CIMV2 WMI namespace" << endl;


    // Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
       pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
       RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
       RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
       NULL,                        // Server principal name 
       RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
       RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
       NULL,                        // client identity
       EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
    );

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
    // Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

    // For example, get the name of the operating system
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
        bstr_t("WQL"), 
        bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem"),
        WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
        NULL,
        &pEnumerator);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed."
            << " Error code = 0x" 
            << hex << hres << endl;
        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;               // Program has failed.
    }

    // Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
    // Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
            &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        // Get the value of the Name property
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"PAEEnabled", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        wcout << " Is PAE enabled? : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        pclsObj->Release();
    }

    // Cleanup
    // ========

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnumerator->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;   // Program successfully completed.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it does return perfectly valid data.
Its just that it only returns a boolean for your call and no bstrVal.

Check the vtProp.vt property against VT_BOOLEAN.
In a VARIANT you always have to check the vt property for the type of data which the VARIANT holds.

---

ORIGINAL Answer:

Your vtProp is a nullptr even tho the HRESULT of the pclsObj->Get() call is S_OK. Most likely it does not find the PAEEnabled property.

When you use the original code from the MSDN example where it uses "Name" instead of "PAEEnabled" it works just fine.

Comment: Yes when i use the original code it works fine and it give me the value of the property "Name" but when i change the property to some other property like PAEEnabled, DataExecutionPrevention_Available, etc.. it gives me that error. What you are saying is that it does not find the value of that property, but is there a way to get these values and how does it not found values for these property? I am experiencing the same problem when retrieving information from Win32_Processor like NumberOfCores, CurrentClockSpeed ...

Comment: Now i understand how to get values for these parameters. Thank you for your answer.